# Use a list to name objects

Tags: r

I have a list

```
l <- list('a','b','c')
```

That I want to use iteratively to create object names in a function. For example:

```
f <- function(){
object <- 1 + 2
}
```

I wanted to run the operation a+b multiple times and each time create a new object with each time naming an object based on something on my list. Is there a way to use a list to iteratively name an object?

I hope this question makes sense...

EDIT:

I am hoping that my output would give me 3 objects:
a, b, and c. Each of these would equal 3 based on the function.

Comment: Not sure what output you are looking for. Can you show what your expected output would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the overall goal is but here's a way to do that :

```
f <- function(){
  object <- p + q
}
p <- 10
q <- 5

list2env(setNames(replicate(length(l), f(), simplify = FALSE), l), .GlobalEnv)

a
#[1] 15
b
#[1] 15
c
#[1] 15
```